# Saving In new File using macro in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Im using the following code, but when I run it, it only saves the last part (& Day(Now) & "-" & Month(Now) & "-" & Year(Now)) of the name. Is not taking into consideration de string "Asesor". I don't know what part I'm missing:

```
Sub SaveFile()

 Dim Asesor As String
 Asesor = Range("B3").Value

Dim DestFile
DestFile = "C:\Users\ST\"

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Workbooks("Grillas_QA.xlsm").Activate
ActiveSheet.Range("A1:K51").Select
Selection.Copy

Workbooks.Add

Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
    SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveWindow.DisplayGridlines = False


Application.DisplayAlerts = False
```

Here's where I save the file.

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=DestFile & Asesor & " " & Day(Now) & "-" & Month(Now) & "-" & Year(Now), _
FileFormat:=xlNormal, Password:="", WriteResPassword:="", _
ReadOnlyRecommended:=False, CreateBackup:=False
```

Thnx in advance for the help.

Comment: try to change `Asesor = Range("B3").Value` to something like this: `Asesor = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B3").Value`. Also this may be interesting: [How to avoid using Select/Active statements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/excel-macro-avoiding-using-select)

Comment: do you want to put it as an answer so I can give you the +1 vote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As follow up from comments, next line

```
Asesor = Range("B3").Value
```

should be changed to something like this:

```
Asesor = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B3").Value
```

Also as a recommendation, I suggest you to read this post: [How to avoid using Select/Active statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/excel-macro-avoiding-using-select)

Comment: I also added to my favourites the avoiding select question. Thnx for that too!

Comment: Usually, using `Select/Active` is the main reason of different runtime errors.